Azure email analytics
I have an azure communication service that sends around hundreds of student invite emails daily, I want to track the mail analytics data like how many mails sent in a day, how many failed how many delivered and how many opened mails using azure sdk's with typescript, any idea how to start with it?
I have'nt tried any sdk's yet in azure, even if it is achievable in other cloud providers it'd be helpful.

You may want to check [ask]

You can use Azure Communication Services to trigger HTTP requests to your Azure Function through webhooks for events like chat messages or incoming calls. Then you can create a TypeScript function to process the events, like sending emails through Twilio SendGrid. Set up SendGrid in Azure, get the API key, and integrate it into your TypeScript app. Aftwards, you can access the tracking data through the Twilio SendGrid dashboard or APIs to monitor the email metrics.
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import * as sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail"; // SENDGRID LIB

// SET SENDGRID API KEY
const apiKey = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;
sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey);

// AZURE()
const sendEmail: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  // Define email content
  const emailContent = {
    to: "HAPPYBONES@HOTMAIL.COM",
    from: "VIMALRAJS@HOTMAIL.COM",
    subject: "TEST EMAIL",
    text: "WELCOME TO YOUR NEW COURSE: SENT VIA AZURE FUNCS AND SENDGRID.",
    trackingSettings: {
      clickTracking: { enable: true },
      openTracking: { enable: true },
    },
  };

  try {
    // SEND EMAIL
    await sgMail.send(emailContent);
    // RESPOND WITH SUCCESS STATUS
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      body: "EMAIL SENT SUCCESFULLY",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // RESPOND WITH ERROR STATUS
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: "EMAIL FAILED TO SEND",
    };
  }
};

export default sendEmail;

